# проблема с датой java

Tags: java

Нужно чтобы пользователь выбрал дату(из календаря), затем она должка записаться в базу, после чего появиться на странице админа, все якобы работает, но дата записывается не правильно(совсем не то число) + не ДД/ММ/ГГГГ, а еще и мин с сек. пишет, кто знает, в чем ошибка, подскажите, буду признателен, 
вот метод:

```
            public void doOrder(String rentTime,Integer durations, String  additionalInfo, long id_client, Date rentDate, String rentObject1) {

            this.initSession();


                Orders ords = new Orders();
            ords.setRentDate(rentDate);
            ords.setRentTime(rentTime);
            ords.setDurations(durations);
            ords.setAdditionalInfo(additionalInfo);

            Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
            try{
            session.beginTransaction();
            Client cl = (Client) session.get(Client.class, new Long(id_client));
            ords.setClient(cl);  

            Query query6 = session.createSQLQuery("select * from RENTOBJECT where THEOBJECT ='"+rentObject1+"'") .addEntity(RentObject.class);
            RentObject selectedRentObj = null;
            List<RentObject> rentObjects = query6.list();
            for (RentObject elem : rentObjects) {
               selectedRentObj = elem;
            }
            ords.setRentObject(selectedRentObj);

            session.save(ords);
            session.getTransaction().commit();
            }
            catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            finally {
            session.close();  
            }
            }
```

Контроллер:

```
               import java.util.Date;


                if (buttonToDoOrder != null){

                    try {

                        String calendar = request.getParameter("calendar");
                        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
                        Date rentDate = sdf.parse(calendar);

                        String rentTime = request.getParameter("menu2");
                        Integer duration = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("duration"));
                        String additionalInfo = request.getParameter("text");

                        String rentObject1 = request.getParameter("menu1"); 

                        long id_client =(long)request.getSession().getAttribute("id_client");                           

                        forClient.doOrder(rentTime,duration,additionalInfo, id_client, rentDate, rentObject1); 
                        response.sendRedirect("StartPage.jsp");

                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(ControllerServlet.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    }

                }
```

в БД дата типа DATE

на jsp стр. вот такой вот кусочек кода:

```
<input type="date" name="calendar">
```

Comment: Возможно дело в часовых зонах. Проверьте чтоб они совпадали в том, что вы получаете и в итоговом объекте типа Date

Comment: честно говоря-не знаю, как это проверить)

Comment: и, кстати, даты не просто неправильные, а нереальные, например 05.12.32

Comment: Ну... Добавьте в вопрос пример того как выглядит дата когда вы вызываете **request.getParameter("calendar")** и после преобразования **sdf.parse(calendar)**. Ведь у вас, быть может, дата приходит в виде миллисекунд с 1970 года, а не в виде ДД.ММ.ГГГГ

Comment: Так а как же глянуть этот промежуточный этап???(извините, что отнимаю Ваше время), или Вы имеете ввиду, написать дату, которую ввожу на стр и дату, которую в БД получаю?

Comment: Ну... В логи вывести, например. Ну и что вводите получаете тоже напишите.

Comment: ввожу 30.06.2015, получаю в базе 06.12.35

Comment: Попробуйте в **SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy")** заменить тире на точки, раз вы с точками дату вводите. И таки разбиритесь с пользованием логами. Без них сложно работать.

Comment: тогда вот что:  java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2015-06-29"
 at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:357)
 at controller.ControllerServlet.doPost(ControllerServlet.java:191)

Comment: на стр календарь, не вручную записую

Comment: Смотрите мой ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В итоге из комментов стало понятно, что

1. На вход вы получаете дату в виде **yyyy-MM-dd**
2. А распознать пытаетесь по шаблону **dd-MM-yyyy**

Так что поменяйте шаблон распознавания на нижеследующий и помните, что порядок чисел в дате важен для её распознования.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Comment: )))спасибо огромное - работает, хотел сначала сразу написать, что уже пробовал и безрезультатно(думал, что уже это делал), хорошо, что перепроверил, еще раз спасибо

Comment: Благодарить тут у нас принято голосованием за ответ и отмечанием его как верного (галочка слева от текста ответа). =)

Comment: буду знать)........

Comment: а может Вы мне еще подскажете почему помимо всего прочего на стр админа еще и час.мин.сек выводит???

Comment: Для этого надо код видеть... Но сделаю предположение: вы там выводите дату через date.toString(); Так оно выведет вместе минутами секундами etc. И лично я просто вручную из даты делаю строку нужного мне вида. Может у класса Date есть какие методы для отображения... Ну или либой какой воспользуйтесь.

Comment: понял, спасибо, попробую